# Attempting to use leiningen to deploy to Archiva... failing

Tags: deployment, clojure, leiningen

I'm stuck trying to deploy a project from leiningen to a local archiva instance.

I've got my project.clj setup correctly (I think)

```
   :repositories  ^:replace [["snapshots" {:url  "http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots"}]
                 ["releases" {:url "http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/internal"}]]
```

when I run 'lein deploy snapshots' I get the error below. Short of starting to try to trace through the code does anyone know what's going wrong here?

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: nth not supported on this type: Character
    at clojure.lang.RT.nthFrom(RT.java:846)
    at clojure.lang.RT.nth(RT.java:796)
    at leiningen.core.user$resolve_credential.invoke(user.clj:67)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:167)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
    at clojure.core$partial$fn__4070.doInvoke(core.clj:2343)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.core.protocols$fn__5888.invoke(protocols.clj:105)
    at clojure.core.protocols$fn__5854$G__5849__5863.invoke(protocols.clj:19)
    at clojure.core.protocols$seq_reduce.invoke(protocols.clj:31)
    at clojure.core.protocols$fn__5879.invoke(protocols.clj:42)
    at clojure.core.protocols$fn__5828$G__5823__5841.invoke(protocols.clj:13)
    at clojure.core$reduce.invoke(core.clj:6030)
    at leiningen.core.user$resolve_credentials.invoke(user.clj:93)
    at leiningen.core.classpath$add_repo_auth.invoke(classpath.clj:85)
    at leiningen.deploy$repo_for.invoke(deploy.clj:40)
    at leiningen.deploy$deploy.invoke(deploy.clj:84)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
    at leiningen.core.main$resolve_task$fn__1602.doInvoke(main.clj:132)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
    at clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke(AFunction.java:29)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
    at leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke(main.clj:167)
    at leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__1661.invoke(main.clj:236)
    at leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke(main.clj:221)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:601)
    at clojure.main$main_opt.invoke(main.clj:324)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:427)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:427)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:172)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
```

Comment: are you useing lein1 or lein2

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you attempt to use  the lein2 :repositoris format with leiningen 1.x. There can be other reasons.

for lein2 the format is:

```
:repositories [["java.net" "http://download.java.net/maven/2"]
               ["sonatype" {:url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"]]
```

(from the [sample project.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/sample.project.clj))

for lein1 the format is:

```
:repositories {"java.net" "http://download.java.net/maven/2"
               "sonatype" {:url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"}}
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but I'm definitely using lein2 and the lein 2 repositories format: [["snapshots" {:url  "http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots"}]
                 ["releases" {:url "http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/internal"}]]